# How to join dba_users table with HRMS oracle tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have request and i would like assistance. I have created this query:

```
 select username, profile, r.GRANTED_ROLE, decode(account_status,'OPEN','ACTIVE','EXPIRED','EXPIRED','INACTIVE') "ACCOUNT STATUS",created, 
 s.PTIME "Password Change Time", last_login 
 from dba_users, dba_role_privs r, sys.user$ s
 where username=r.grantee(+)
 and username=s.NAME
 order by 1;
```

So i am ok with it, but i wanted to know how can i join personal database accounts with some of Oracle's HRMS table in order to get for them details like email, employee_id etc.

Comment: What is the question: what is the table name for the information you need or how to write join on some conditions?

Comment: Both will be good, i think that i can use per_all_people_f table, but problem is that my usernames are first character of name following last name. Can i somehow incorporate join search for database users which are personal and provide details for them in one go?

Comment: Does HRMS provides a possibility to assign personal DB accounts to people (in general it is done via some governance system, not HR system)? Sounds like this question cannot be answered because it depends on your naming conventions.

Comment: I'm trying to somehow join employee details with current personal database accounts. Because dba_users do not provide employee details information I'm seeking some tables where i would be able to join theirs last name, for example MKING. If MKING exists in dba_users, and i can find his last name in one of HRMS tables, i could provide details for that username in corresponding dba_users table.